# Twitter Ruby Gem - Check if user revoked access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have a twitter enabled (using https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) app up and running on a ruby on rails application. I track whether the user has logged in to twitter by storing info in the local database. Same goes for if the user decides to log out via my application. However, I have no way of accounting for if the user revokes access to the app through the twitter website. What's the best way to check if the application access has been revoked?